# Systemmodstamp question

Tags: apex

I am running below query. The expectation is to retrieve the result if an update happened on the account or the user record. however, when i execute the query, i can see that the systemmodstamp was updated on the user record but there were no updates on the user record itself. The lastModifiedDate is displayed from december 2023. In which case, user record systemmodstamp will be updated as compare to lastModifiedDate and i would like to test the example as well to confirm the behavior.

```
Select id from account where 
(SystemModstamp >= 2024-01-24T09:30:36Z OR Account.Owner.SystemModstamp >=2024-01-24T09:30:36Z)
```

When running the above query, the data is the same but account.owner.systemodstamp shows something got updated but the lastModifiedDate still shows lastYear record

Comment: So what is the "Systemmodstamp question"? I assume you have googled Systemmodstamp vs. LastModifiedDate?! Sorry, I don't get what remains unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some specific differences between these fields and how they are managed, as covered in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387261&type=1).

My guess here is, given that it is the User values in question, that Salesforce is performing some internal processing that changes the SystemModstamp but does not cause a last modified change.

Comment: So the account is perfectly fine since the lastModified & systemmodstamp matches. However, the owner of that account  (which is the user record) shows somehting was modified but it is a system user and is more controlled by our admins and they also confirmed that nothing was updated. SO i am trying to understand what would have updated on the user record that is only updating systemmodstamp and not lastmodifiedDate